# angular ui tabs active based on ui-router state

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui

I'm getting this error:

```
Error: [$compile:nonassign] Expression '$state.current.name==='admin.adminDetails'' used with directive 'tab' is non-assignable!
```

Trying to activate tabs based off of url:

```
<tabset direction="right" class="tabbable">
    <tab heading="Details" ui-sref="admin.details" active="$state.current.name === 'admin.details'">
        <div ui-view="adminDetails"></div>
    </tab>
    <tab heading="Resources" ui-sref="admin.resources" active="$state.current.name==='admin.resources'">
        <div ui-view="adminResources"></div>
    </tab>
</tabset>
```

I'm doing it this way so when the url is /admin/resources then the tab will open on the resources tab and same with the details.

Any insight into this error?

Comment: Hi! Shouldn't it be **uib-tabset** and **uib-tab** instead of just _tabset_ and _tab_? If you're using angular-ui-bootstrap, then the active attribute expects a number, not a boolean.

Comment: i'm on version 0.13.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `ui-sref-active="active"` instead og `active`.
This applies the class "active" to the element.

Should be used alongside with `ui-sref`. [Docs](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.directive:ui-sref-active)